Passing a context using koin annotations missing Definition type
I have the following module where I am creating sharepreferences
@Module
@ComponentScan
class SharedPreferenceModule {

    companion object {
        private const val FILE_NAME = "secret_shared_prefs"
    }

    @Single
    fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        val masterKeys = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)

        return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
            FILE_NAME,
            masterKeys,
            context,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
            EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        )
    }
}

I get this error:
e: [ksp] --> Missing Definition type 'android.content.Context' for 'di.provideSharedPreferences'. Fix your configuration to define type 'Context'.

I am just asking why I can't annotate the function with the @single?
In my application class I have the following:
 startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@BusbyTravelMateApplication)
            modules(
                networkModule,
                repositoryModule,
                useCaseModule,
                userModule,
                SharedPreferenceModule().module
            )
        }

And I am trying to inject into this class
class UserTokenLocalDataSourceImp(private val encryptedSharedPreferences: EncryptedSharedPreferences)
    : UserTokenLocalDataSource {

    companion object {
        private const val TOKEN = "token"
    }

    override suspend fun saveUserToken(token: String) {
        encryptedSharedPreferences.edit {
            this.putString(TOKEN, token)
            this.apply()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun fetchUserToken(): String? {
        return encryptedSharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null)
    }
}

UPDATE

